# Group all elements of Pandas Dataframe by Datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine a Dataframe with 3 columns:

```
index
A: datetime
B: value 1 or 2
```

There could be more rows for a specific day. I want to make a new dataframe which summarize the value for each day. So:

```
index
A: datetime (1 day)
B: amount of rows which contained value 1 in first dataframe
C: amount of rows which contained value 2 in first dataframe
```

Sample data:

[image]

Comment: show us some sample data

Comment: I added some sample data to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby` with something like:

```
df['count_sentiment'] = df['Sentiment'] == 'positive' # equal to 1 iff the row is positive
df[['Date', 'Likes', 'Rts', 'count_sentiment']].groupby(by='Date').sum()
```

where `df` is your dataframe. 
This will group by Date. If you want to group by day, create another column `Day` with the day you want to group with and replace `groupby(by='Date')` by `groupby(by='Day')`

Comment: what are the first 2 rows?

Comment: I updated the rows to match your question, and added comments